# Make City and Postcode both required fields in WooCommerce Shipping Calculator

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field

How do you make both City and Suburb fields required in WooCommerce Shipping Calculator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can copy the shipping-calculator.php template to my child theme and then add the 'required' attribute to both the postcode and city input fields which prevents the field from being empty, that works fine.

```
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_city_field">
        <input type="text" required class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->customer->get_shipping_city() ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'City', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" name="calc_shipping_city" id="calc_shipping_city" />
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_postcode', true ) ) : ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_postcode_field">
        <input type="text" required class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode() ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Postcode / ZIP', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" name="calc_shipping_postcode" id="calc_shipping_postcode" />
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If it's possible to do via a WooCommerce php snippet I'd like to know, rather that than the template way.

Answer (score 0):

Or, validate data via the filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_shipping_address', function( $address ){ 
    if ( empty( $address['postcode'] ) && empty( $address['city'] ) ) {
        throw new Exception( __( 'Please enter a postcode and a city name' ) );
    } elseif ( empty( $address['postcode'] ) ) {
        throw new Exception( __( 'Please enter a postcode' ) );
    } elseif ( empty( $address['city'] ) ) {
        throw new Exception( __( 'Please enter a city name' ) );
    }
    return $address;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible by jQuery in a document ready function...

```
$('#calc_shipping_city, #calc_shipping_postcode').prop('required', true);
```

This would avoid using a woocommerce template.